# How to make pencil stroke for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing, stroke

I would like to make a pencil stroke in an iPhone application, which can draw lines such as you can see in this picture:

[image]

Can anybody show me how I could implement these types of stroke?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172107/draw-lines-and-fills-with-a-chalk-texture-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 4):

There are no built-in functions for drawing this kind of stroke.  You will have to come up with your own texture image and draw it repeatedly along the path.  There are no built-in functions for getting points along a path either.

Comment: one thing more, if i work in this way then it will not change its color from color palet

Comment: Indeed.  You need to make the texture image be a grayscale image.  At each point where you want to paint the texture, you need to set it as the clipping mask, then fill its bounding box with your desired color.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to obtain what you're looking for... Probably the best solution (and more complicated) is using OpenGL ES.

Try to take a look at this sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html